# How to change accent of TextToSpeech dynamically in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

In my app we can change language dynamically. I've written following code to set textToSpeech language

```
 if (textToSpeech!!.isLanguageAvailable(CountryConfiguration.locale) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
            textToSpeech!!.language = CountryConfiguration.locale
        }
```

but it is not changing accent of speech. Accent of speech is default locale of device.

Is there any way to change accent of speech?

Answer (score 0):

Check this : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

```java
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK))
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.FRANCE))
mTts.isLanguageAvailable(new Locale("spa", "ESP")))
```